# .Net - regular expression to clean the junk chars

Tags: php, .net, regex, encryption

Can some one please help me to convert the following the PHP stuffs to .Net?

I don't enough idea in .Net and I need a regular expression to washout the junk chars from a decrypted string.

```
function clean($val) {
  return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-|||!@#$%&*. ]/', '', $val);
}
echo clean($val)
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What do you mean by .NET? C# or VB.NET? Or any other language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way in C#:

```
private string CleanStr(string val) 
{
   return Regex.Replace(val, @"[^A-Za-z0-9\-|!@#$%&*. ]", string.Empty);
}
```

And then in the caller:

```
Console.WriteLine(CleanStr("<<<Go>>>"));
```

Result: `Go`